# Mouse Click on JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I have a bunch of code that displays data in a Grid using Jtable. I need to capture the mouse double click event. But some how this simple code is just working on the Header of the grid but not working on the rows of that that Grid. Any clue? One more thing, the grid is editable as well.

Thank you.

Regards.
Manish

Comment: *this simple code* : which simple code?

Comment: crossposted https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2332433&tstart=0

Comment: What do you mean "any clue"? You where given the reason for this behaviour yesterday in your cross posted question.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your code would be helpful.  Are you doing something similar to this?

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !e.isConsumed()) {
        e.consume();
        // handle double click here
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, code is working fine on non-editable row. But how can i do the same for editable row? the

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as

```
class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;

  private String label;

  private boolean isPushed;

  public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }
```

here you can provide any component instead of button.
refer [full example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm)